Need access to the Facebook app on developers.facebook.com
Our public facing website has an integration with facebook to allow users to login. It is currently throwing an exception when it tries to - "Error Accessing App. We're sorry, but the application you're trying to use doesn't exist or has been disabled." while trying to login to facebook.
I do not have the facebook email and password which was used to setup the app (as the previous developer who set it no longer works with us) so that I can login to "developers.facebook.com" to check if the application is disabled or inactive for some reason (possibly compliance), so I can activate or fix the issue myself. All I have is the Client Id and Client Secret which is used to integrate with the graph API programatically.
Is there a way to get hold of the email/password for the business facebook account using just the Client Id and Secret or should I just create a new account?
I also tried accessing the facebook app info using Graph API via the OAuth token (derived from the Client Id and Secret), but it wasn't very useful. All I know is the app Category (business), App Id and Name. I was hoping to find an API to maybe tell me the status of the app and possibly to activate it.
